# Can I post useful code snippets instead of asking a question?

Tags: discussion, source-code

Is it okay to post something other than a question on Stack Overflow?

Instead, could we share some code that might help users in their daily coding? Like sharing some useful Javascript snippets, a useful function created in php, etc?

Comment: no. what i'm saying is that not to ask question. just post your useful codes for others

Comment: Did you read the linked question and its answers? Just dumping code on the site is not okay. Asking a question, *"How do I foo the bar?"* and then posting your code snippet as an answer saying, *"This is one way to foo the bar"* is allowed. Code dumped in a question is useful to nobody since nobody will find it. What are you asking if this is not a duplicate?

Comment: easy bro! :D hahaha! this is not duplicate of the link in your first comment. better to understand my post. :D

Comment: Sorry, I haven't earned the Mind-Reader Hat yet. If you want the community to support your idea, the onus is on you to properly explain what it is you want. We have a method for sharing your own code using the current system. I have linked it. You tell me that is not what you want, but haven't explained how your idea differs. So perhaps you could [edit] your question to make it clearer to those of us lacking telepathy or omniscience?

Comment: you don't get my point bro! :D do you check my post? :)) ow "Mind-Reader" that's awesome huh. If I know, you only got that term to other user :))))

Comment: @jmac, I don't see how that is a duplicate, it's just a related question. OP here is asking whether it's okay to just post useful code, not whether it's okay to post a useful question/answer combination at once. The answer to the OP here, of course, is "no", and posting a question/answer at once is a viable alternative, but it's still a different question.

Comment: yeah right bro! @benlee. pretty obvious that is a different question.

Comment: Yes user3069157, I don't get your point. That is why I am asking for an [edit] to clarify what it is you are trying to do, and how self-answering a question to allow people to find your code in the future doesn't address your concerns. Telling me I don't understand doesn't help me understand. @Ben, I am confused as to how one would post useful code in some way other than a question/answer combo. How is this not asking for the rules on how to post useful information?

Comment: @jmac, the question is already closed as duplicate, so looks like the community outnumbers me on this one. I concede the point.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, but it's an interesting idea. SO is strictly for answering questions. Perhaps make a blog, and link to it from your profile page? That would create a sort of intermediary, you get people to come to your page from SO, but it's not on SO.

However, if you can create a question that would be answered by your code, you can post an answer to your own question with a thorough explanation.

Comment: thanks bro! got an good answer to my post.

Comment: github gists would also work well in theory.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just post on Stack's Code Review? You get opinions (and votes). With tags I would say the reverse about @scrblnrd3's answer: you can get the Stack badge and link to profile, which ultimately links to the code you've posted.

Comment: That's not what Code Review is for.

Comment: @Makoto My SUV is not for banging, but if I could...I would. Doesn't stop it from being an SUV. :)

Comment: Also doesn't stop the police from parting you from your SUV, and further judicial branches preventing such an act ever occurring again.

Comment: @Makoto You have to agree it would have been worth it ;).

Comment: I would politely disagree.  Besides, we're getting way off topic here.  Point stands - [doesn't seem like this sort of question would belong on Code Review.](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Makoto Point taken. I just meant that he could post his "useful" code to get it reviewed. "This is Javascript for xyz" versus "What do you think about this Javascript for xyz?" A subtle change in his approach and, based on my reading of that link, he can post code snippets. I get that it counters the intended purpose, but can we agree that unintended actions can be useful sometimes?

Comment: @REMESQ If you're posting code snippets on code review for the purposes of just sharing code snippets, you're wasting everyone's time. You're wasting yours because you spent it sharing code snippets in a place nobody looks for them (because it's _not for_ code snippets), and you're wasting your reviewers' time because you don't care about getting your code reviewed.